# Error message for empty textfield for a JCombo box

Tags: java, eclipse, jcombobox

I have created a JComboBox in order to add players to a list as I am creating a game. I am trying to show an error message using JOptionPane if the text field is left empty I did this using the method below.

```
    btnAddPlayer = new JButton("Add Player");
    btnAddPlayer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { //This is the layout for the list of points that are possible to achieve
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {     
            if (txtAddPlayer.equals("")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(btnAddPlayer, this, "Please Enter Full Details", NumofAnswers);//THIS IS THE METHOD I TRIED 
                } else {
                    comboBox.addItem(txtAddPlayer.getText());
                }
        }
    });
    btnAddPlayer.setBounds(469, 243, 89, 23);
    panel.add(btnAddPlayer);
    txtAddPlayer = new JTextField();

    txtAddPlayer.setBounds(373, 244, 86, 20);
    panel.add(txtAddPlayer);
    txtAddPlayer.setColumns(10);
```

I am not sure why this is not working. Please provide an answer using my code. 
Regards,

Comment: if (txtAddPlayer.length()<0)

Comment: So what _does_ happen?

Comment: It does not provide an error message and allows empty components to be added to the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be
    If (textField.gettext().equals(""))